# Bash Script rename file to modified day and add suffix

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rename, suffix

```
| Filename | DateModified | After Rename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa.mp3 | 20230114 | 20230114_1.mp3 |
| bbb.mp3 | 20230113 | 20230113_1.mp3 |
| ccc.mp3 | 20230114 | 20230114_2.mp3 |
| ddd.mp3 | 20221205 | 20221205_1.mp3 |
| eee.mp3 | 20230113 | 20230113_2.mp3 |
```

I have a folder "/volume1/music/" with multiple random named mp3 file inside.

I want to rename file to date modified and add inscrease suffix to advoid same name.

I use the code below but don't know how to handle the counter suffix

```
cd "/volume1/music/"
counter=1
for file in *.mp3; do
    cdate=$(date -r "$file" +"%Y%m%d")
        echo "$cdate"
        if [ -f "$cdate" ]; then
            set counter=counter+1
        else 
            set counter=0
        fi
    echo mv "$file" "$cdate"_"$counter"
done
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the counter initialisation inside the loop,
and increment by repeatedly testing existence of full name rather than just date string.

You can add a test to avoid renaming files that already have the correct name format.

```
cd "/volume1/music/"

for oldfile in *.mp3; do
    cdate=$(date -r "$oldfile" +"%Y%m%d")
    echo "$cdate"

    if [[ $oldfile =~ ^[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{1,}\.mp3$ ]]; then
        if [[ $oldfile =~ ^"$cdate" ]]; then
            echo "skipping $oldfile"
            continue
        fi
    fi

    counter=1
    while
        newfile="${cdate}_${counter}.mp3"
        [ -e "$newfile" ]
    do
        (( counter++ ))
    done

    echo mv "$oldfile" "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the "counter" seem not work. I have the log 20230112
mv 0fb7efd887d6fd786326109421e8c3e4_64k.mp3 20230112_1.mp3
20230112
mv 1b2d9e0695cd51b119c57a7938d826e6_64k.mp3 20230112_1.mp3
20230112
mv 7a892dbe427c75712d095c5b1fefc178_64k.mp3 20230112_1.mp3
20230112
mv 8b38603e9b5ddb9f019af97c95451ee5_64k.mp3 20230112_1.mp3
20230114
mv aaa.mp3 20230114_1.mp3

Comment: As other answer shows, also worth checking `cd` and `date` succeed (so wrong folder is not renamed, and files not misnamed); and that `*.mp3` matches some files (otherwise `mv` will give error)

Comment: this is because you don't actually create the renamed files (`echo mv ...` vs `mv ...`) so the existence test fails early

Comment: Thank your very much. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> I use the code below but don't know how to handle the counter suffix

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /volume1/music/ || exit

shopt -s nullglob extglob

for file in ./!([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9]*).mp3; do
  counter=1
  ext="${file##*.}"
  cdate=$(date -r "$file" +"%Y%m%d") || exit
  if [[ -n "$cdate" ]]; then
    echo "$cdate"
    while [[ -e "$cdate"_"$counter"."$ext" ]]; do
      ((counter++))
    done
    echo mv -vn "$file" "$cdate"_"$counter"."$ext" || exit
  fi
done
```

---

- Remove the `echo` if you think the output is ok.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the same below jhnc's code, the counter alway 1.

Comment: Remove the `echo` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Thank your very much. It works as expected.